# How to map values from a email to case description dynamically in apex?

Tags: apex, inboundemail

I have an email to case set up in my org which creates cases with subject and description. Description is a long text area field which contains the email body which has like firstname, lastname, email, linkt To The Website. I am currently replacing all the newlines in the string along with using a substring to fetch the data like firstname, last name etc. But sometimes the substring that I am looking for is changing in the email. For example, I sometimes receive 'link To The Website' and the other times it is like 'Direct link'. So, my question is how do I dynamically identify these values so that I can update the case.

Here is my code.

```
@InvocableMethod(label='Case Data' description='Case Data')
public static List<List<String>> getData (List<FlowInputs> request) {
    
    List<List<String>> outputList = new List<List<String>>();
    
    List<String> emailTextList = request[0].emailText;
  
    String firstNameString = emailTextList[0].substringBetween('firstname : ','lastname');

    // Add string values into a list
    List<String> stringList = new List<String>{firstNameString};

    outputList.add(stringList);
    
    return outputList;
}
```

Any pointers are appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you can, exploit the values in `Case.SuppliedName` to get first/last

[From the doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cases_fields.htm&type=5)

> Web Company   Company name provided by a customer who created a case from Web-to-Case or Email-to-Case. ApiName = `SuppliedCompany`
>
> Web Email  Email address provided by a customer who created a case from Web-to-Case or Email-to-Case. ApiName = `SuppliedEmail`
>
> Web Name   Customer’s name as provided by a customer who created a case from
> Web-to-Case or Email-to-Case. ApiName = `SuppliedName`
>
> Web Phone  Phone number provided by the customer who created a case from Web-to-Case or Email-to-Case. ApiName = `SuppliedPhone`

You can split apart the `SuppliedName` by space and take the first token to be the First Name and the remaining tokens to be Last Name.  Cleverer algorithms exist to handle names like `Billy Sue Briggs` versus `Joe van Gustav` or `Hannah de la Cruz`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but then I was also wondering about how do I get 'link to the website' ?  @cropredy

Comment: for that, you'll need to parse the Description field using apex regex support; I was trying to point out that some of the parsing can be avoided because the values are in the OOTB fields